# Laravel - checking record existence

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently my db tables are defined as below:

**site_roles** - Contains different roles

**site_user_roles** - Links Users to many roles

**site_permission_modules** - Contains different access levels [eg. view admin controls, ban users]

**site_role_permissions** - Links permission modules to roles

My models in laravel are correctly defined to query these many to many relations. In code I want to check if a user has a certain permission module linked to him.

For better understanding, here are my models as well:

**User**

```
public function SiteRoles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SiteRole', 'site_user_roles', 'users_id', 'site_roles_id');
    }
```

**SiteRole**

```
public function Users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'site_user_roles', 'site_roles_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function SitePermissionModules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SitePermissionModule', 'site_role_permissions', 'site_roles_id', 'site_permission_modules_id');
    }
```

**SitePermissionModule**

```
public function SiteRoles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SiteRole', 'site_role_permissions', 'site_permission_modules_id', 'site_roles_id');
    }
```

Here is what I currently did:

```
Auth::User()->SiteRoles()->with('SitePermissionModules')->get()
```

The with() keyword retrieves a nested array of permissions associated with each role.

I need to check if the user has a specific permission module linked to him.

What would be the best laravel way to do this?

EDIT:

*Basically I'm just asking what would be the best way to chain 2 many to many relationships.*

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::User()->SiteRoles()->with(['SitePermissionModules' => function ($query) {
                                   $query->where('site_role_permissions','=','admin'); 
                                      //use where as per your requirment.

}])->get();
```

[Querying Relaionship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)